# Delphi, using vbscript for connecting ADO, new Be

Tags: delphi, vbscript, ado

Connecting to ADO is hard from installation in Delphi, so I decided to use VBscript, which I have never used before.  VBscript has little support in Delphi, so how do I run a Windows script editor to get support and carry it over to Delphi? I do not understand the statements in VB script very well yet

1. My Delphi TTable is connecting to
   the ADO
2. I need to connect to a
   Microsoft DB file in c:\program
   files\common\my folder\my file
3. I need to disconnect the ADO to
   relocate this file and place a new
   copy in its place periodically.

I looked up the MSN web site and it's not that helpful.
I see scripts that could be useful for many things if I can get them working.

Can anyone help please?

Lex Dean

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, lexdean. Always glad to see a newcomer.  Let me give you a few pointers about etiquette here. The interface looks a lot like a forum, but we don't *quite* behave like one. The "answer" button is specifically for *providing an answer,* not for other things such as leaving a comment. Also, posting an email address and asking for assistance to be sent there is frowned upon. This site is meant to be a public Q&A site where answers get provided not only for you, but also for people in the future with the same problem. Anyway, I hope you find a good answer! :)

Comment: @Whoever voted to close: He's brand new.  Go easy on him.  I edited the post for readability.  Anyone here know how to make VBScript work in Delphi?

Comment: Lex Dean, you want to use VBScript with Delphi because you don't understand how to use ADO from Delphi, but you also don't understand VBScript. I think you should select one of the two (Delphi or Visual Basic) and stik to it, and if you need to work with ADO, just ask a clear question: "How do I work with ADO from Delphi?" If you choose Delphi then go to the search box in the upper-right corner and type "[delphi] ADO" in there: This instructs StackOverflow to show you question about ADO tagged "Delphi". The result set is impressive.

Comment: @lexdean: You should ask the SO administrators to join your at least 7 "lex dean" and "lexdean" accounts.

Comment: Do you want to 1: Execute VBScript code from within Delphi, or 2: Convert VBScript to Delphi code?

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use the native (and easy) ADO components in Delphi.

You will found a example of 'how to do', with source, here :
http://sourceforge.net/projects/axbase/

Answer (score 1):

- You do not connect *to* ADO. You connect to a DB *through* ADO. ADO is a technology to connect to different databases using a common API - the database native API is taken care of by ADO drivers.
- You say you need to connect to a "Microsoft DB" file but do not specify what kind. ADO can connect directly to Access files, but if you use SQL Server you never connect to a file, you connect to the database server.
- Delphi has a different set of components to connect through ADO. They are the TADOxxxx component. TTable is built upon the BDE, and can't use ADO. Use TADODataset or TADOTable.
- Using VBScript from Delphi is possible, but would not solve your problem easily - you will have to pass ADO objects to and from Delphi and VBScript, and it requires a good knowledge of Delphi, Windows, COM and so on. If you need to use ADO, take the straight path.